# convert mebibyte to gigabyte

Tags: javascript, numbers

How can I convert mebibyte to gigabyte? Currently I'm just converting from megabytes to gigabytes.

```
export function megabyteToGigabyte(n: number) {
  return n / Math.pow(10, 3);
}
```

But what about mebibytes?

Comment: According to google for an approximate result, divide the digital storage value by 954
Type: convert mebibyte to gigabyte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 Gigabyte is approximately 954 mebibyte

So you can simply divide `n` by 954 to convert MiB to GB

```
function MebibyteToGigabyte(n){
  return n / 953.674; // 953.674 is the exact number
}
```

Comment: Note that 953.674 is not actually the exact conversion factor. 953.67431640625 is as close as I could compute.

Answer (score 1):

Convert to bytes: 1 mebibyte = 1048576 bytes

Then convert to gigabytes: 1 gigabyte = 1000000000 bytes

This gives you:

```js
const MiBToGB = n => n * 1048576 / 1000000000;

console.log(MiBToGB(1000)); // 1.048576
```

Answer (score 0):

Mebibyte(MiB) is a binary, unit, defined as 2^20 or 1024^2 Bytes.

So, 1 MiB = 1,048,576 Bytes

Whereas, Gigabyte(GB) is a decimal unit, defined as 10^9 or 1000^3 Bytes.

That makes 1 GB = 1,000,000,000 Bytes

To convert *n* MiB to GB, we have to multiply *n* with 1,048,576 and divide with 1000,000,000

for e.g. 1 MiB to GB = 1 * 1,048,576 / 1000,000,000 = 0.001048576

From above, the simplest way will be to just multiply *n* with 0.001048576.